# CodeIgniter view anchor tag prepending host

Tags: codeigniter

In my view I'm trying to create an anchor tag but CodeIgniter is prepending my entire host before what I specify as href, therefor making it invalid.
I put this

```
<a href="file://////path_to/file/file.jpg">My File</a>
```

I get

```
<a href="http://localhost/index.php/file://////path_to/file/file.jpg">My File</a>
```

EDIT 3
This is my view, I realise i should not be calling a function in my view but in this case I had little option as something needs to get applied for each data item in the loop, I will try to change this but thats beyond my problem right now.
Wesley: I checked the soruce and it displays correctly in the source but in the browser it preappends the host so I guess this has nothing to do with code igniter afterall! How do I make sure it doesn't happen?

```
            <td><?php 
            $this->ci = &get_instance(); 
            echo $currentData["field_one"] . " - <a href=\"file:://///" . $this->ci->myfunc($currentData["field_one"]); . "\">Log</a>"; ?>
            </td>
```

---

EDIT 4

**my html source**

```
<a href="file:://///\\myhost.local.com\120">
View Log
</a>
```

**my url address bar**

```
http://myhost.local.com/myhostlocal/index.php/level/one/type/b/cc/ee/
```

**the url it goes too when I mouse over the href**

```
http:///myhostlocal/index.php/level/one/type/b/cc/ee/file:://///\\myhost.local.com\120
```

Comment: Are you using the `anchor()` function or not? Codeigniter is not going to do anything to raw HTML, if that is indeed what you are using. Are you seeing this in the HTML source or the browser status bar? If you are using php to generate the link, please make sure to point that out.

Comment: Hi Wesley yes I am using php to generate the link like so echo "<a href=\"file://////path_to/file/file.jpg\">logs</a>";

Comment: What I'm asking is if you see the wrong path in the HTML source or not. I'm testing this now and having different, but still undesired behavior. Testing in a static HTML file is working fine however. Try playing with the `$config['uri_protocol']` perhaps.

Comment: @user391986 I don't think any of the URL Helper functions supports what you wanna do, better create your own function to do that.

Comment: @atno: He's not using any helper functions.

Comment: @Wesley oh frack you're right. :) I'm gonna test that, weird.

Comment: @user391986 it works as expected for me. Can you paste your view in your question? I'm curious

Comment: Can you paste some of your view's code?

Comment: Wesley, the source looks as expected I just don't understand why I'm getting the preappended host when I mouse over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the browser is treating "file:://///" as a relative path. Why do you have 2 colons, do you need both? Removing one will provide a valid protocol, and the browser will start treating it as an absolute path.